Get filename from URL with wild cards
This code fetches a file from ARCH_URL. However, there is a manifest file on the same page, which will always have the current ARCH_FILE with the current timestamp in the filename. How could I read that manifest to make sure I'm always fetching the current file of ARCH_TYPE?
import re
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from pathlib import Path

ARCH_TYPE = "stage3-amd64-desktop-systemd"
ARCH_URL = "https://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/amd64/autobuilds/current-{0}/".format(ARCH_TYPE)
ARCH_FILE = "{0}-20240609T164903Z.tar.xz".format(ARCH_TYPE)
FILEPATH = Path(ARCH_FILE)
SRC_URL = "https://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/amd64/autobuilds/current-stage3-amd64-desktop-systemd/{0}".format(ARCH_FILE)

# Get current stage3 filename:
with urlopen(ARCH_URL) as response:
    html_response = response.read()
    encoding = response.headers.get_content_charset('utf-8')
    decoded_html = html_response.decode(encoding)
sub_str = '{0}-.*.tar.xz'.format(ARCH_TYPE)
temp = re.compile(sub_str)
res = temp.search(decoded_html)
# The result includes the .tar.xz.asc immediately followed by the .tar.xz.
# So we need to weed out the .tar.xz.asc filename and the double-quote and angle bracket that come after it.
# The following line is: result[substring-starts-with-angle-bracket-plus-one:the-entire-result-length-to-the-end]
print("The substring match is : " + str(res.group(0))[str(res.group(0)).find('>')+1:len(str(res.group(0)))])


What do you mean by "fetch"? How would that be different from the code you already have? Do you simply mean that you want the regex to only match a filename ending in .tar.xz and not match something ending in .tar.xz.asc? In this case, you have a regex question, not a question that has anything to do with HTML or anything else; and it's also a fundamental piece of regex knowledge that I can give you a duplicate for.

Did you notice there's a signed manifest file in that directory that contains the name of the latest archive? You can just parse that.
import requests

type = "stage3-amd64-desktop-systemd"
url_base = f"https://gentoo.osuosl.org/releases/amd64/autobuilds/current-{type}/"
manifest_resp = requests.get(f"{url_base}latest-{type}.txt")
manifest_resp.raise_for_status()

xz_filename = None
for line in manifest_resp.text.splitlines():
    if line.startswith(type) and ".tar.xz" in line:
        xz_filename = line.split()[0]
        break

if not xz_filename:
    raise ValueError("Didn't find the URL")
xz_url = f"{url_base}{xz_filename}"
xz_resp = requests.head(xz_url)  # switch this to `.get()` if you want the bytes too
xz_resp.raise_for_status()
print(xz_url, "is", xz_resp.headers["content-length"], "bytes long")

At the time of writing, this prints
https://gentoo.osuosl.org/releases/amd64/autobuilds/current-stage3-amd64-desktop-systemd/stage3-amd64-desktop-systemd-20240609T164903Z.tar.xz is 461071584 bytes long

